Replace create_function with ?? for PHP 8
I've got a wordpress blog running on a old PHP 7.4 installation... and i will update to PHP 8.0.3 or higher !
// Only show the meta box if there are fields to show.
if ($this->get_postmeta_array($screen))
    add_meta_box(
          'su_postmeta'
        , __('Show Settings', 'look-ultimate')
        , create_function(
              ''
            , 'global $look_ultimate; $look_ultimate->show_postmeta_box("'.$screen.'");'
        )
        , $screen
        , 'normal'
        , 'high'
    );

How could I rewrite this code, unfortunately there is no longer any support from the manufacturer  ??
thanks in advance
doesent work:
    function ('$screen') {
        return 'global $look_ultimate; $look_ultimate->show_postmeta_box("'.$screen.'");'
    )
    , $screen, 'normal', 'high')
}

